# Hibernate component mapping of an immutable object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an immutable object which is a member of a Hibernate persisted object using component mapping. Example, `PinDrop` corresponds to a table, which has a field of type immutable `Point`:

```
public class PinDrop {
    private String name;
    private Point location;
    // Getters and setters for name and location
}

// Immutable Point
public class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;
    // Getters for x and y, no setters
}
```

In my `PinDrop.hbm.xml`:

```
<property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
<component name="location" class="Point>
    <property name="x" column="location_x" type="double"/>
    <property name="y" column="location_y" type="double"/>
</component>
```

This doesn't work because at runtime Hibernate complains that `Point` doesn't have setters for `x` and `y`. Is there a way to use an immutable object as a component of a Hibernate persistent object?

**Follow-up**: I'm not using annotations, but rather `hbm.xml`. Neither `mutable` nor `immutable` are valid attributes on `component` and `property` in `hbm.xml`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tell hibernate to use field access (attribute `access=field` in your hbm) so hibernate won't complains about missing accessors.

Hibernate use reflection to modify the final fields so it should work.

Comment: I didn't believe this would work, but it does. Apparently final fields can be modified using reflection. I wonder what implications this has with the Java memory model, since final fields are guaranteed to be thread safe and properly visibile to all threads.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate doesn't really like immutable objects. Your best options are either

- Use pseudo-immutable objects that don't use the `final` keyword, but that have no setters, and then tell Hibernate to set values via fields.
- Have hibernate populate mutable builder object, and then have that copy its properties into a proper immutable object. Unfortunately this means have two classes for each BO/DTO.

Comment: I like this first option better than setting final fields via reflection. Setting final fields is too weird and, like Steve commented, may mess with otherwise-valid thread safety assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [@Immutable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html) annotation?

> Mark an Entity or a Collection as immutable. No annotation means the
>   element is mutable.
>
> An immutable entity may not be updated by the application. Updates to
>   an immutable entity will be ignored, but no exception is thrown.
>   @Immutable must be used on root entities only.
>
> @Immutable placed on a collection makes the collection immutable,
>   meaning additions and deletions to and from the collection are not
>   allowed. A HibernateException is thrown in this case.

As far as I know for making a table immutable in *.hbm.xml, `mutable="false"` attribute can help.

Comment: Where would I stick this in the `hbm.xml` file?

Comment: The table isn't immutable, but rather the component